# How to handle exceptions in Cluster

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, parent-child

I have a below code

```
//Start.js

var file1 = require('./file1.js'),
    file2 = require('./file2.js'),
    connectDomain = require('connect-domain'),
    connectRoute = require('connect-route'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    app = connect();
    app.use(connectDomain()) // For error handling
       .use(connectRoute(function (router) {
        router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
            file1.writeFile(req, res); // Writing the file and storing in DB
            file2.readAllFiles(req,res); // Reading the file from DB
        })
    }))

app.listen(1000);
```

1. Both file1.writeFile(req, res) and file2.readAllFiles(req,res) are
   executing parallely.
2. In file1.writeFile(req, res), all DB error will
   be handled by connect Domain. If any file write error occurs I want
   to throw an exception to file2.readAllFiles(req,res).
3. How can I implement my above code in cluster nodejs? 
   Any help on this will be
   really helpful.

Comment: Actually, those functions aren't executing in parallel, unless they're asynchronous.

Comment: Since DB operation in  file1.writeFile(req, res) will take time, so file2.readAllFiles(req,res) starts running

Comment: I don't know what is in `file1` or `file2` but from the way you're using the functions they're quite synchronous-looking to me.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But any idea of how to implement cluster on it?

Comment: Did you try [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) ?

Comment: @user568109 Yes i tried running this code var options = { exec: "Start.js" };
        cluster.setupMaster(options);
        var worker = cluster.fork().process; But Im not able to catch the failed scenario